# Is space of $C^1$ functions with finite support a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

If the product is defined as 
$$(f,g) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)\overline{g'(x)} \, dx$$

then is the space of continuously differentiable functions with finite support an inner product space?

I initially thought No because if $f$ is the Cantor function then $(f,f)=0$ however $f\neq 0 $.  While $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and is continuous everywhere.... maybe it is not $C^1$ because we require more than just a.e. continuous differentiability to be in $C^1$?

Comment: It is an inner product space, but *not* a Hilbert space. Its completion is the Sobolov space $H^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We require everywhere differentiability, with a *continuous differentiate* for functions in $C^1$.

But you're on the right track, exactly the *constant* functions will have $(f,f)=0$ with respect to this positive semidefinite bilinear form.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!!  I appreciate you answering the questions as asked!

Comment: This is not true. The only constant function with finite support is the zero function. Hence, $(f,f) \ne 0$ for all $f \ne 0$.

Comment: Does the notation $C^1$ mean *compactly supported*?

Comment: It means continuously differentiable.  So in this setting we are working with continuously differentiable functions with finite support.

Answer (score 0):

It is an inner product space, but it is not complete ( so, not a Hilbert space).